# RequiredFieldValidator and preventing CausesValidation

Tags: asp.net, html, requiredfieldvalidator

I've got a [RequiredFieldValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hbw267h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on a contact form.

It works as intended when people click 'Submit', but if they click 'Cancel' or any of the multiple menus on my form, the [RequiredFieldValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hbw267h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) cancels the action.

I have already searched and found that I need to set the other controls on my form using [CausesValidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.causesvalidation.aspx) = **False** (using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915530/bypassing-a-requiredfieldvalidator) post), but do I have to do that for every control on my page?

What makes it worse is that the menus on my form are contained in a Master.Page, and they are mostly `<DIV>` style CSS buttons, but clicking any of the buttons causes the [RequiredFieldValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hbw267h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to fire and fail the form.

Shouldn't the default be False and I have to turn on which control sets the validation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can set validation groups

```
             <asp:TextBox ID="tb1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ValidateMe" />
             <asp:TextBox ID="tb2" runat="server" />
             <asp:RequiredFieldValidator" ID="rfv1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tb1" ValidationGroup="ValidateMe" />
               ...
             <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ValidateMe" />
```

came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636200/asp-validation-off-by-default)

Edit , sorry I didn't put put this in code properly and it didn't display:

Or you can always use  and handle those on client side if they are just cancel and stuff like that

```
         <input type="button" >
```

Comment: The [ValidationGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.validationgroup.aspx) worked. I don't understand how that eliminated the hyperlink behavior, though.

Comment: Because the hyperlinks do not "know" the validation group. They only validate the unnamed (empty string "") group by default.

Comment: Thanks - I had a similar issue w/ hyperlinks that navigate the tabs in the jqueryui tabs widget and ValidationGroup fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

You only need to set:

```
  CausesValidation = False
```

To your buttons performing an action

As an alternative, you could add a `ValidationGroup` attribute to your controls and buttons to control *which buttons raise the validation*. Only the controls matching the `ValidationGroup` specified will be validated

Comment: I only have 1 Cancel button. I never noticed this freakish behavior until I wasn't able to physically navigate off of the Contact form using any of my hyperlinks on the page. If I set `False` on the Cancel button, will that also apply to all of the links?

Comment: mm nope, either set `CausesValidation=false` to each button/link or set the `ValidaitonGroup` to your validators and controls. An alternative, you could iterate throgh all your controls on the form and set the `CausesValidation=false` then just override to `true` the buttons you would like to fire the validaiton

Comment: OK, another +1. That was what I was afraid I was going to have to do (iterate over all controls on the form and set `CausesValidation=False` - stupid ASP.NET). Luckily, I was able to use the [ValidationGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.validationgroup.aspx) concept presented by Scott Selby above, and it was able to solve my issue with less effort. Thanks!